# jasmine-maven-plugin + phantomJS : Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: angularjs, maven, phantomjs, jasmine-maven-plugin

I create a project with :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.github.searls -DarchetypeArtifactId=jasmine-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.1.5 -DgroupId=com.acme -DartifactId=my-jasmine-project -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

First I test with **mvn jasmine:test** the test are run normally.

note : I use maven 3.2.1

In the "target" directory I add a folder "phantomjs-1.9.7-windows" where I put "phantomjs.exe"

I modifie my original pom.xml to add

```
                ...
    <configuration>
        <srcDirectoryName>${project.artifactId}/src/main/javascript</srcDirectoryName>
        <webDriverClassName>org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver</webDriverClassName>
        <webDriverCapabilities>
            <capability>
                <name>phantomjs.binary.path</name>
                <value>${project.build.directory}/phantomjs-1.9.7-${os.phantomJS}/${run.phantomJS}</value>
            </capability>
        </webDriverCapabilities>


        <preloadSources>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/javascript/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js</source>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/javascript/libs/angular.js</source>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/javascript/libs/angular-ui-router.js</source>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/javascript/libs/angular-resource.js</source>
        </preloadSources>
    </configuration>
    ...
```

I create a folder "libs" under "src/main/javascript" and I put in it : 
- jquery-1.9.1.js
- angular.js
- angular-ui-router.js
- angular-resource.js

note : angular is in verion 1.2.23

After that I create an other folder "app" under "src/main/javascript" and I put in it : "app.module.js"

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [
         'app.Security.modules'
    ]);
})();
```

Under "src/main/javascript/app" I create a folder "security" and I put in it : "security.module.js"

```
(function() {
'use strict';
    angular.module('app.Security.modules', []);
})();
```

and "cha_directive.js"

```
angular.module('app.Security.modules').directive('inputOld', InputAccessKeyManagement);
function InputAccessKeyManagement () {}
```

If I test with **mvn jasmine:test** I obtain an error :

```
[ERROR - 2015-02-26T08:12:49.751Z] Session [40eacc20-bd8f-11e4-a736-9934c466a5ff] - page.onError - stack:
  (anonymous function) (http://localhost:51170/jasmine-project/src/main/javascript/libs/angular.js:1679)
  ensure (http://localhost:51170/jasmine-project/src/main/javascript/libs/angular.js:1601)
  module (http://localhost:51170/jasmine-project/src/main/javascript/libs/angular.js:1892)
  (anonymous function) (http://localhost:51170/jasmine-project/src/main/javascript/app/security/cha_directive.js:1)
[WARNING] JavaScript Console Errors:

  * Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.Security.modules' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/nomod?p0=app.Security.modules


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.163s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 26 09:12:49 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/210M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.searls:jasmine-maven-plugin:1.3.1.5:test (default-cli) on project jasmine-project: The jasmine-maven-plugin encountered an exception:
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: There were javascript console errors.
[ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.runner.SpecRunnerExecutor.execute(SpecRunnerExecutor.java:46)
[ERROR] at com.github.searls.jasmine.mojo.TestMojo.executeSpecs(TestMojo.java:86)
```

**If I just rename** "cha_directive.js" **in** "toto_directive.js" (with the same source code) and I run **mvn jasmine:test** again the test are run normally.

If I use "cha_directive.js" name file and run **mvn jasmine:bdd**. After that I run the url http://localhost:8234 in FF the tests are run normally.

The only thing (if I edit the HTML code of "Jasmine Spec Runner" with fireBug) is that I can see this tag  :

```
<head jmp_jserror="Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.Security.modules' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/nomod?p0=app.Security.modules">
```

If I look in class SpecRunnerExecutor.java in "checkForConsoleErrors" there is a test :

```
WebElement head = driver.findElement(By.tagName("head"));
if (head != null) {
    String jserrors = head.getAttribute("jmp_jserror");
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jserrors)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("There were javascript console errors.");
    }
}
```

note : other file name crash the tests : input_directive.js, accessKey_directive.js, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem of import script order.

I declare

```
(function() {
   'use strict';
   angular.module('app.Security.modules', []);
})();
```

in a file named "**s**ecurity.module.js"

and I try to use my declaration

```
angular.module('app.Security.modules')
  .directive('inputOld', InputAccessKeyManagement);
  function InputAccessKeyManagement () {}
```

in a file named "**c**ha_directive.js"

If you don't specify a custom import script order the default one is alphabetical then "**c**ha_directive.js" is before "**s**ecurity.module.js".

I solved the problem using a "customRunnerTemplate".

But maybe there was another way to do "prettier" ?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes across this, a good solution is to do something like this in your sourceInclude block:

```
<sourceInclude>
  <include>**/*.module.js</include>
  <include>**/*.controller.js</include>
  <include>**/*.service.js</include>
...
```

Et cetera. Assuming you conform to having your modules defined in a file called something along the lines of 'example.module.js' the modules will be loaded first, then controller, et cetera